# Как в функции получить указатель на нить, которая её вызвала?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Создаю нить:

```
std::thread *thr = new std::thread(&MyClass::threadFunc, this);
```

Как теперь в функции `MyClass::threadFunc()` получить указатель на нить, которая её вызвала?

Comment: Зачем Вам это? Стандартного способа не существует.

Comment: чтобы чистить его из списка главного объекта...

Comment: Вам предложили один вариант, но, на мой взгляд, что-то у Вас не так. Можете подробнее, с кодом, показать, чего Вы хотите добиться?

Answer (score 3):

Если бы поток можно было запустить остановленным, то

```
struct Args { MyClass* cls; std::thread* thread; };
auto args = std::make_shared<Args>();
args->cls = this;
args->thread = new suspened_thread(&MyClass::threadFunc, args);
resume_thread(args->thread);
```

Но в стандартной библиотеке такого нет, по этому надо использовать какой-нибудь объект синхронизации, например `std::future`:

```
struct Args { MyClass* cls; std::future<std::thread*> thread; };
std::promise<std::thread*> promise;
auto args = std::make_shared<Args>();
args->cls = this;
args->thread = promise.get_future();
promise.set_value(new std::thread(&MyClass::threadFunc, args));

void threadFunc(std::shared_ptr<Args> args) {
    auto thread = args->thread.get();
    ...
```